# This translate in the logic predicate is true or not

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I found in a book , this phrase :
`There is a man who loves all women`.

the logic predicate is : $\exists x(m(x)\wedge\forall y(w(y)\wedge love(x,y)))$
or not

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not. The problem is found in the part $\forall y(w(y)\wedge love(x,y))$, because that means that all people are women and loved by the man $x$. A proper formula would be the following:

$$\exists x(m(x)\wedge\forall y(w(y)\rightarrow love(x,y)))$$

In which case now it says that if $y$ is a woman, then $y$ is loved by $x$.

Comment: I do not understand !!!!!!

Comment: Which part didn't you understand?

Comment: @HachoAlihous If I say $\forall x (Dog(x) \land Has4Legs(x))$ then I say that *everything* is a dog and has 4 legs (so you would be a dog and have 4 legs too!).  But if you say $\forall x (Dog(x) \rightarrow Has4Legs(x))$, then you just say that all dogs have 4 legs ... everything that is not a dog may or may not have 4 legs ... and we are certainly no longer claiming that everything is a dog!  But in your original sentence you are saying that everything is a woman ... including the man himself!

Comment: i'm used tow variables  , X and Y 
 ∃x(m(x)∧∀y(w(y)∧love(x,y)))  ! 
Give me an example with tow variables

Comment: Ok, take your own statement: it says: 'there is a man such that everything is a woman and loved by this man'. So, that means that ths man is a woman, and loved by himself, because *everything* is a woman and loved by this man.  But that is of course not what we intended to say.